# Como pasar datos de una clase a un label o textbox de un form a través de hilos?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos

Buen dia compañeros, les escribo ya que estoy intentando mandar un estatus que se va a mostrar en un label ya que de esta forma me indicara en que proceso se encuentra. lo estoy realizando a traves de hilos pero no me funciona ,me podrian ayudar en como realizarlo?
mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
class ClaseContenedora:form1
{
   public void test()
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();

        Thread t = new Thread(()=>f.CambiarEstatus("cambio test"));
        t.Start();

    }
}
```

Este es el codigo desde el form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 private void btnEjecutar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {

            ReporteadorAdeudosPredial.Controller.AdeudosController ac = new Controller.AdeudosController();
//Aqui mando llamar al metodo de la otra clase
            ac.test();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.ErrorLog(ex.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(),"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
   delegate void CambiarEstatusDelegado(string texto);

    public void CambiarEstatus(string texto)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            CambiarEstatusDelegado d = new CambiarEstatusDelegado(CambiarEstatus);

            object[] parametros = new object[] { texto };

            this.Invoke(d, parametros);
        }
        else
        {
            lblEstatus.Text = texto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cómo que no te funciona? Qué error tenes? alguna Excepción? Falta información para poder ayudarte...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás creando un nuevo formulario dentro de `ClaseContendora` que es el que estás cambiando, pero no es la instancia de `Form1` que tu aplicación muestra. Así que terminas haciendo el cambio, pero no lo ves porque lo haces en otro objeto.

Una opción es que la instancia de `ClaseContenedora` tenga como dependencia la instancia de `Form1` y sobre ese objeto hacer los cambios.

Para eso, debes modificar la `ClaseContenedora`.

- Agrega un constructor y un campo a la clase para recibir la instancia de Form1:

  ```
  private readonly Form1 _form;

  public ClaseContenedora(Form1 form)
  {
      _form = form;
  }
  ```
- Edita el método `test()` de `ClaseContenedora` para invocar el método de `CambiarEstatus()` del form recibido por parámetro en el punto anterior.

  ```
  public void test()
  {
      Thread t = new Thread(() => _form.CambiarEstatus("cambio test"));
      t.Start();
  }
  ```
- Edita el manejador del evento click `btnEjecutar_Click()` en `Form1` para pasarle a `ClaseContenedora` el formulario actual.

  ```
  var ac = new ClaseContenedora(this);
  //Aqui mando llamar al método de la otra clase
  ac.test();
  ```

Espero te sirva.